# socket -V- rest performance

Tags: java, sockets, rest

I have done some searching but haven't come up with anything on this topic. I was wondering if anyone has ever compared (to some degree) the performance difference between an RPC over a socket and a REST web service. If both do the same thing, which would have a tendency to be the better performer? I've already started building some socket code and would like to know if REST would give better performance before I progress much further. Any input would be really appreciated. Thanks indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its hard to imagine that REST is faster than a simple socket connection given it also goes over a Socket.

However REST may be performant enough, standard and easier to use. I would test whether REST is fast enough and meets your requirements first (or one of the many other existing solutions) before attempting your own Socket solution.

Comment: Good point. I suppose I'll just have to try both and see which is the optimal.

Comment: Writing your own solution can be more fun and interesting. You just need to have a clear idea of why you are doing a particular thing. ;)

Answer (score 4):

RMI

> Feels like a local API, much like
>   XMLRPC
>
> Can provide some fairly nice remote
>   exception data
>
> Java specific means this causes lock
>   in and limits your options
>
> Has horrible versioning problems
>   between different versions of clients
>
> Skeleton files must be compiled in
>   like CORBA, which is not very flexible

REST:

> easy to route around firewalls
>
> useful for uploading files as it can
>   be rather lightweight
>
> very simple if you just want to shove
>   simple things at something and get
>   back an integer (like for uploaders)
>
> easy to proxy security behind Apache
>   and let it take the heat
>
> does not define any standard format
>   for the way the data is being
>   exchanged (could be JSON,  YAML 1.0,
>   YAML 2.0, arbitrary XML format, etc)
>
> does not define any convention about
>   having remote faults sent back to the
>   caller, integer codes are frequently
>   used, but method of sending back data
>   is not defined. Ideally this would be
>   standardized.
>
> may require a lot of work on the
>   client side caller of the library to
>   make use of data (custom serialization
>   and so forth)

In short from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100993/rmi-vs-web-services-whats-best-for-java2java-remoting)

> web services do allow a loosely
>   coupled architecture. With RMI, you
>   have to make sure that the objects
>   stay in sync in all applications
>
> RMI works best for smaller
>   applications, that are not
>   internet-related and thus not scalable